# Using generate_series with Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm having a difficult time rewriting pure SQL query for **generate_series** with **Rails ORM**.

First, to explain what I'm going for.

**My mission** is to extract sum(total) of invoices from date interval user chooses by each month. Easy.

So, If users choose 2019 year, the result is something like:

```
Month | total_sum
2       500
3       600
5       700
```

Problem is, the result is only with months that exist in invoices.

To fix that, I want to fill gaps with `generate_series`, SQL function for months that are missing.

I came up with SQL that is something like this:

```
WITH 
range_values AS (
  SELECT date_trunc('month', date_start) as minval,
         date_trunc('month', date_end) as maxval
  FROM transactions),

months_range AS (
  SELECT generate_series(minval, maxval, '1 month'::interval) as month
  FROM range_values
),

monthly_sum AS (
  SELECT date_trunc('month', payment_date) AS month,
         SUM(total)   AS total
  FROM transactions
  GROUP BY month
)

SELECT date_part('month', months_range.month),
        coalesce(monthly_sum.total, 0) AS total
FROM months_range
LEFT JOIN monthly_sum ON months_range.month = monthly_sum.month;
```

The result is what I expect, but I want to chain this method with an existing relation.

I'm came up with:

```
@relation.joins("LEFT JOIN generate_series(TIMESTAMP '1-1-2018', TIMESTAMP '1-1-2021', interval '1 month') AS series ON transactions.payment_date = series")
.group("series")
.select("series, sum(transactions.total)"`)
```

Rails generated query:

```
SELECT series, sum(transactions.total) 
FROM transactions 
LEFT JOIN generate_series(TIMESTAMP '1-1-2018', TIMESTAMP '1-1-2021', interval '1 month') AS series ON transactions.payment_date = series 
GROUP BY series
```

Result in rails is:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Transaction id: nil>]>
```

### #

**NOTE**: I'am expecting something like Array of [{"series" => 'x', "total" => 'y'},{#...},#...] NOT `Transaction` objects

If I run this generated SQL in *pgadmin*, the result is:

```
series | sum
null     5881
```

Using:

- Rails 5.2
- Postgresql 9.1

### EDIT

What I got for now, but not getting results yet:

```
  def group_total_by_months
   @relation.joins("RIGHT JOIN generate_series(TIMESTAMP '1-1-2018', TIMESTAMP '1-1-2020', interval '1 month') AS series
                     ON date_trunc('month', transactions.payment_date) = series")
            .group("series")
            .select("series, sum(transactions.total) AS total")
  end
```

result:

```
#<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<Transaction id: nil, total: 0.61173e3>, #<Transaction id: nil, total: 0.364446e4>, #<Transaction id: nil, total: 0.1625e4>]>
```

The result is correct for 3 months, but missing the date series.
to_sql:

```
   SELECT series AS payment_date, sum(transactions.total) AS total FROM 
 \"transactions\"
 RIGHT JOIN generate_series(TIMESTAMP '1-1-2018', TIMESTAMP '1-1-2020', 
          interval '1 month') AS series ON date_trunc('month', 
          transactions.payment_date) = series 
WHERE \"transactions\".\"account_id\" = 1 
GROUP BY series
```

What I want to achieve:

```
WITH filteret_transactions AS (
    SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE transactions.account_id = 1
)

 SELECT series AS payment_date, sum(filteret_transactions.total) AS total 
    FROM  filteret_transactions
  RIGHT JOIN generate_series(TIMESTAMP '1-1-2018', TIMESTAMP '1-1-2020', interval '1 month') AS series
  ON date_trunc('month', filteret_transactions.payment_date) = series GROUP BY series
```

Comment: What type of Object are you anticipating being returned, a `Transaction`?

Comment: I'm expecting aggregated data by the sum of total and grouped by months of the year, so not a transaction object. Do I need to edit my question to be clear?

Comment: You are going to need to retrieve some kind of `ActiveRecord` object if you want an `ActiveRecord::Relation` in return. If a `Array` of `[{"series" => 'x', "total" => 'y'},{#...},#...]` is acceptable then the answer changes dramatically.

Comment: Hash of results is acceptable, I dont need `Transaction` objects here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following should work for you

```
def sums_by_month_range(date1,date2,relates_to, date_column: :payment_date, sum_column: :total)
  relation_table = Arel::Table.new(:relation)
  relation = Arel::Nodes::As.new(relation_table, relates_to.arel) 
  month_range_table = Arel::Table.new(:month_range)
  month_range = Arel::Nodes::As.new(month_range_table,
    Arel::SelectManager.new.project(
      Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('date_part',[Arel.sql("'month'"),Arel::Attribute.new(Arel::Table.new(:series),'month')]).as('month')
    ).distinct.from(
     Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('generate_series',[Arel.sql("date '#{date1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}'"),Arel.sql("date '#{date2.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}'"),Arel.sql("'1 month'::interval")]).as('series(month)').to_sql
    )
  )
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(
    month_range_table.project(
      month_range_table[:month],
      relation_table[sum_column].sum.as('total')
    ).with(month_range, relation).join(relation_table, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin).on(
      Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('date_trunc',[Arel.sql("'month'"),relation_table[date_column]]).eq(month_range_table[:month])
    ).group(month_range_table[:month]).to_sql
  ).to_hash
end
```

to recreate your second example this can be called as:

```
sums_by_month(Date.new(2018,1,1),Date.new(2021,1,1), @relation)
```

This will return an `Array` of `Hash` as `[{'month' => x, 'total' => y}]` you can modify as you see fit. The query will look like

```
WITH month_range AS  (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    date_part('month', [series].[month]) AS month 
  FROM 
    generate_series(date '2018-01-01', date '2019-01-01', '1 month'::interval) AS series(month)
), relation AS ( 
  [WHATEVER AR QUERY OBJECT YOU PASS IN]
)
SELECT 
   month_range.month,
   SUM(relation.total) AS total
FROM 
   month_range 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN relation ON date_trunc('month', relation.payment_date) = month_range.month
GROUP BY 
   month_range.month
```

**TL;DR**
This will reproduce your exact query (Example 1 in post)

```
transaction_table = Transaction.arel_table
range_values_table = Arel::Table.new(:range_values)
range_values = Arel::Nodes::As.new(range_values_table,
  transaction_table.project(
    Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('date_trunc',[Arel.sql("'month'"),transaction_table[:date_start]]).as('minval'),
    Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('date_trunc',[Arel.sql("'month'"),transaction_table[:date_end]]).as('maxval')
  )
)

month_range_table = Arel::Table.new(:months_range)
month_range = Arel::Nodes::As.new(month_range_table,
  range_values_table.project(
    Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('generate_series',[range_values_table[:minval],range_values_table[:maxval],Arel.sql("'1 month'::interval")]).as('month')
  )
)

monthly_sum_table = Arel::Table.new(:monthly_sum)
monthly_sum = Arel::Nodes::As.new(monthly_sum_table,
  transaction_table.project(
    Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('date_trunc',[Arel.sql("'month'"),transaction_table[:payment_date]]).as('month'),
    transaction_table[:total].sum.as('total')
  ).group(Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('date_trunc',[Arel.sql("'month'"),transaction_table[:payment_date]])))

query = month_range_table.project(
  Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('date_part',[Arel.sql("'month'"),month_range_table[:month]]).as('month'),
  Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new('coalesce',[monthly_sum_table[:total],Arel.sql("0")]).as('total')
  ).with( 
    range_values,
    month_range,
    monthly_sum
  ).join(monthly_sum_table, Arel::Nodes::OuterJoin).on(monthly_sum_table[:month].eq(month_range_table[:month]))

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_query(query.to_sql).to_hash
```

generated SQL

```
WITH range_values AS (
    SELECT 
        date_trunc('month', transactions.date_start) AS minval, 
        date_trunc('month', transactions.date_end) AS maxval 
    FROM 
        transactions), 
months_range AS (
    SELECT 
        generate_series(range_values.minval, range_values.maxval, '1 month'::interval) AS month 
    FROM 
        range_values), 
monthly_sum AS (
    SELECT 
        date_trunc('month', transactions.payment_date) AS month, 
        SUM(transactions.total) AS total 
    FROM 
        transactions 
    GROUP BY 
        date_trunc('month', transactions.payment_date)) 

SELECT 
    date_part('month', months_range.month) AS month, 
    coalesce(monthly_sum.total, 0) AS total 
FROM 
    months_range 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN monthly_sum ON monthly_sum.month = months_range.month
```

Comment: Why did you use Arel lib directly from an active record? This can be achieved with a query I'm suggesting with right join. This is the first time I see this approach of making queries in rails. Note: my query does not to be the same as suggested, but the result needs to be what I'm seeking.

Comment: @codemonkey 1) you didn't want Transactions (which is what you have returned) 2) I despise raw sql in Active Record as it is far less adaptable if you wanted to change any part of the query

Comment: The model(transaction) is there as a base for my query, but the results I'am getting aren't instances of Transactions any more. I won't get an id for the record anymore more.

Comment: @codemonkey but the class is still a `Transaction` just a bastardized and nearly useless version of one. One of the most confusing and less useful "features" of rails. If I saw that I had a Transaction object I would expect it to act like a Transaction object yet for these objects that is not the case at all. Second you need to join the Transaction to the series not the other way around in order to achieve your goal. Thus my answer.

Comment: Oh, we misunderstood each other. Thank you for explaining that for me. I edited my question and yes I need to join transaction to series, so that's why I used RIGHT join not LEFT any more.

Comment: @codemonkey since you decided to repost this question can explain what issue you have with my solution? It appears to fit your need perfectly so I am trying to understand

Comment: your solution is working, but I don't understand Arel lib that much to understand what are you doing here. Not only that, everyone on the project needs to know what is this code doing and maintaining.  Also, I was trying to learn more about using ActiveRecord with raw sql as I wrote the question, hoping I can get a sophisticated solution in 5 lines of code (rails way). I have more than a few like these functions, my query object would look like a bunch of text.

Comment: And the point is to use existing relation not sending all those params. In that way, it's easier for me to just write raw sql. I didn't find a solution for my idea, probably because it can't be done in that way.

Comment: @codemonkey very well although Arel is "the rails way" everything you do in rails breaks down to Arel before execution. If you want to use a CTE (`with`) you are going to have to use Arel to do it. Also to your point "use existing relation not sending all those params"  my code allows you to pass in the relation. You would pass this as the `relates_to` parameter as shown `sums_by_month(Date.new(2018,1,1),Date.new(2021,1,1), @relation)`.